# Decoupling Item and ItemManager relationship

Tags: python, software-design

Consider the following code:

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self):
        self.properties = {}
        self.baseItemId = None

    def evaluate():
        baseItemProperties = ItemManager.LookupById(self.baseItemId).properties
        ...
        do stuff

    ...

class ItemManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def downloadItems():
        ...
        adds items to self.items
```

I have a list of items maintained by ItemManager, populated from user files and some downloaded. After every download I'd run evaluate on the items, to update their contents. But for evaluate to be able to determine the base item to be used it needs access to a id->item lookup table. This feels wrong to me as suddenly Item needs to be aware of ItemManager.

Is this ok design? is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Usually you want to avoid circular references. If `Item.evaluate` needs to know about something that is not part of the item state it can just ask for it as a parameter.

Comment: If it is common for items to be loaded in the manager, but never evaluated, then this makes sense to me. Otherwise, I would probably just make properties a member and set it on the item at load. This is more of a https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ question.